# getfile() is failing on 1st try but working on second, how can i fix this?

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to get a file location from the user. I've used the same `getfile` function on dozens of programs with no issues. For some strange reason this one always returns a cannot open file on the 1st try but then accepts it on the 2nd try. I have tried a `cin.clear();` before the `getline` where I get the file location but that was no help. I cant figure out why this is acting so weird. Here is my `getfile` function:

```
void maze::getfile()
{
    string filename;
    char X;


    cout << "please enter the location of the file you wish to input: " << endl;
    getline(cin, filename);
    cin.ignore(100, '\n');

    inData.open(filename.c_str()); //opens file

    while (!inData) //while the file is accesible
    {
        cout << "The file could not be opened.\nPlease try again: " << endl;
        //error message for input validation
        getline(cin, filename);
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        inData.open(filename.c_str());
    }



    for(int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        for(int u = 1; u < 11; u++)
        {
            inData >> X >>ws;
            if(X == '1')
                X = 219;
            if(X == '0')
                X = ' ';
            floor[i][u] = X;
        }
    }
    floor[0][0] = 201;
    floor[0][11] = 187;
    floor[11][0] = 200;
    floor[11][11] = 188;

    for(int i=1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        floor[0][i] = 205;
        floor[11][i] = 205;
        floor[i][0] = 186;
        floor[i][11] = 186;

    }

    inData.close();
}
```

The only thing that happens before this is the main menu call. I set a variable `choice =` to a main menu function that returns a char, in this case '1'.  Any ideas why it's failing on the first file input and not the 2nd try with the same file?

Comment: once inputting the file for a second time and printing the maze everything looks perfect. so the program does work, just not as cleanly as I want it to

Comment: `X = 219;` this is going to overflow (undefined behavior) unless your platform's `char` is `unsigned`.

Comment: X = 219 seems to be working, it sets the char to a solid block which I use to make a wall character. the first time I input the file I get the "the file could not be opened" which means something is wrong with the file location or with opening the file. But I drag and drop the same file in again and everything is all good. its not making any sense to me.

Comment: "X = 219 seems to be working" This is one valid outcome of undefined behavior, another is Bjarne ringing your doorbell and sucker punching you when you open the door, you're just lucky it's the former. As for your file issue, it sounds like the problem may be elsewhere.

Comment: lol ok I'll make it unsigned. thanks for the advice.

Comment: putting cin.ignore(100, '\n') before the 1st getline fixed it. I have no idea why I needed it this time since I have implemented this function the exact same way many times before and never needed it.

Comment: Are you performing any other input or output before you call this function? Perhaps reading an integer from `std::cin`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you left a newline(maybe `scanf()`, `cin>>`, `gets()` left in) in the stream before you call `std::getline` first time, so that it gives you an empty string for the `filename`, after that, newline is eaten, so it works fine second time.